# how to output solr core name with log4j

Tags: logging, solr, log4j

Solr4 outputs entries like:

```
10:56:55.689 [searcherExecutor-5-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore - [core0] Registered new searcher Searcher@7a85b031 main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_14:228601 _27j5(4.3.1):C18335161/2313734 _257a(4.3.1):C24349255/2326527 _210g(4.3.1):C18306979 _287n(4.3.1):C1927648 _28af(4.3.1):C249307 _28re(4.3.1):C1161428/12826 _28fz(4.3.1):C260567/1021 _28uh(4.3.1):C266582/2057 _2997(4.3.1):C685637/436232 _296j(4.3.1):C493665/2540 _29a8(4.3.1):C37183/15132 _29bb(4.3.1):C66208 _29bl(4.3.1):C66457 _29bv(4.3.1):C66385 _29c5(4.3.1):C67350 _29cf(4.3.1):C68403 _29bs(4.3.1):C6783 _29d0(4.3.1):C66027 _29cq(4.3.1):C66629 _29cz(4.3.1):C6405 _29d1(4.3.1):C6421 _29d2(4.3.1):C5058)}
```

with the following line in log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Notice the core name core0 in square brackets.

Is it possible to ask Solr to output core names always to assist readability? For example the following entry does not get stamped with a core name which makes it practically impossible to follow on which core is doing that:

```
11:24:25.134 [commitScheduler-6-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.UpdateHandler  - end_commit_flush
```

Are there any other Solr specific logging flags you could recommend to increase the readability and help debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That needs to be done in the Solr code, it can't be done by configuration.  Many existing logs do include [corename] in them.  Others don't, either because the core name is not readily available at the point in the source code where the log is generated, or none of the committers that touched the souce code thought about it.

Please file an issue in Apache Jira indicating which logs (Java classes) you'd like to see the core name on, and/or come back to #solr during US business hours to discuss it further.

This is an issue I've been thinking about lately myself, and I'd like to get the [corename] paradigm extended across more of the logs in the codebase.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Filed a jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5277